# How to capture what is visible through a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, screenshot

Suppose I have an image and a div whose position is absolute and is above that image (z-index of div more than z-index of image).Something like this : [image]

I want to take screenshot of what is visible through the div using JavaScript. At first I thought of changing the div to a canvas and then I wrote this code:

```
<div class="utility-btn">
        <button class="enquiry-btn" onclick="openEnquiry()">?</button>
    </div>
    <div id="enquiry">
        <button id="close" onclick="closeEnquiry()">X</button>
        <div class="cover">
            <canvas id="capture"></canvas>
            <button class="btn" onclick="takeScreenshot()">
                Click to enquiry
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Function to take screenshot:

```
function takeScreenshot() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('capture');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var backCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            backCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            backCanvas.height = canvas.height;
            var backCtx = backCanvas.getContext('2d');

            backCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

            ctx.drawImage(backCanvas, 0, 0);
            var dataURL = backCanvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(dataURL);
        }
```

But the image of dataURL was not what I expected it was just a blank image:[image]

How can I implement this feature. How can I do it without using any external library?

Comment: Are  you seeing any errors in your browser's devtools inspect facility console (e.g. is the img from an external source so you get some message about 'tainted'?) [I can't see where you draw the initial image].

Comment: No I am not getting any errors or warnings

Comment: Can you make a runnable snippet, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In particular, how are you getting and drawing the initial image onto the canvas?

Comment: Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/tushar-bharti/pen/poaQgeG?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

### #1

If we look at your bit of code responsible for actually taking the screenshot

```
        function takeScreenshot() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('capture');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var backCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            backCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            backCanvas.height = canvas.height;
            var backCtx = backCanvas.getContext('2d');

            backCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

            ctx.drawImage(backCanvas, 0, 0);
            var dataURL = backCanvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(dataURL);
        }
```

we can see that `canvas` is the element you want to have the screenshot taken onto. Later on you're creating an empty new canvas `backCanvas` and make it the size of the first canvas. Afterwards you're drawing the empty first canvas on the second and finally the empty second canvas back to the first.

So that does not make too much sense.

Instead you need to take the actual canvas generated by threeJS. These lines of your code append a `<canvas>` element to the container `<div>`, threeJS is using:

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

We can reference it using:

```
document.getElementById("container").children[0]
```

### #2

As threeJS uses WebGL to draw stuff, it's rendering context is not the regular and for performance reasons the browser is clearing the drawing buffer after something has been drawn onto - so your screenshot would come up empty all the time. There is an option you need to pass to the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` constructor to keep the drawingbuffer called `preserveDrawingBuffer`.

So change this line:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

to this

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

and your screenshot function to this:

```
function takeScreenshot() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('capture');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("container").children[0], 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);
}
```